# Bootstrap Modal to popup after successful submission of the form

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would need to know the code on how Bootstrap Modal Will popup after successful submission of the form.

Comment: has your form ajax submission or not?

Comment: because when you submit a form its redirect to method attribute of form that sat by developer.